# Best practice for factor and reverse in R

Tags: r

I have a variable that has on one column some strings; so for further processing I have converted them into factor:

```
myVar$strCol <- as.factor(myVar$strCol)
```

Now I want to get back the strings for writing the output. I have tested and it seems that there are more possibilities to do the reverse of `as.factor`. I have found:

```
as.character(myVar$strCol)
```

and

```
factor(myVar$strCol)
```

I am confused, now. Which is the best one? Which is the fastest one? Which one shall I use? Is it another one that is better?

Any help please, I am new to R?

Comment: To convert from factor to character, use `as.character`.

Comment: To find the fastest, you can do some benchmarks with `system.time` or using `library(microbenchmark)` on a large dataset.  For example. `set.seed(24);v1 <- factor(sample(letters[1:5],1e7, replace=TRUE));  system.time(as.character(v1));  system.time(levels(v1)[v1])`

Comment: The `factor` function does not reverse the action of `as.factor`. Only the `as.character` function performs that service. There are some functions such are the ones providing regex services and time and date translation which will do the `as.character` operation implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the print output from those two objects  is identical if they are in a data.frame, the result is completely different. Furthermore, in most cases of an R newbie looking at this, it will be the case that looking at the content of a dataframe with "character variables" reveals them to be factors. (That presumption may now be incorrect. The new behavior since R v4+ of the read.* functions is no longer to make all character columns "AsFactors". Sofor the last year factors need to be specifically created.

Bottom line: Only the first option you presented will deliver what you asked for.

You should learn to examine R objects with `str()` and present them to SO audiences with `dput()`-output so that the ambiguity of the console-print method can be avoided.

```
> test <- factor(1:10)
> test
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> dput( as.character ( test) )
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
> dput( factor (test) )
structure(1:10, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10"), class = "factor")
```

Although the "character" column has no hint that it is a factor, it still is one in the `dd`-object below:

```
> dd <- data.frame(test=letters[1:10], num =1:10)
> dd
   test num
1     a   1
2     b   2
3     c   3
4     d   4
5     e   5
6     f   6
7     g   7
8     h   8
9     i   9
10    j  10
> dput(dd)
structure(list(test = structure(1:10, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), class = "factor"), num = 1:10), .Names = c("test", 
"num"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: So supposing that I have a file.csv that contains the values that dd contains (a, b ...) and I make it `as.factor` after reading the values. After processing, I want to save the result in out.csv so it will contain the letters instead of numbers, how would you suggest me to do? (If it is not clear, I'll edit the question tomorrow)

Comment: `as.factor` will not do anything to things that look like "character" columns, because they are already factor by default. Only if you had included the parameter `stringsAsFactors`=FALSE in the `read.csv` call would there be any change. Converting the output from factor to character should not be necessary when the file will be in a text-format. You should either ask another question or amend this one to put in some code to address this further question.

Comment: Generally one would use `factor` rather than `as.factor`. It no  a matter of efficiency, but rahter of flexibility. the `factor` function allows more choices for setting levels. And as always, just executing the funciton is not enough. One needs to assign the result to a name.